# Sample skewness consistency

Tags: skewness, consistency

Is sample skewness a consistent estimator of (moment coefficient)  skewness?

I have ran some experiments and it seems this is not the case, but I cannot find any definite answer online.

Here is an example:
[image: simulation]

Comment: Consistency should trivially follow from the law of large numbers. Maybe you can share the details of your experiments so we can see why you think it is not the case

Comment: @J.Delaney: done. Thank you for your help

Comment: Consistency means that in the limit $n \to \infty$  you result should converge to the true value which is $\approx 6.18$ with your parameters. How fast does it converge and what is the variance of the sample skewness (namely what value of $n$ you need in order to get an estimate with a given standard deviation) are other issues: It could be that you just need a larger sample size to get a better approximation

Comment: @J.Delaney. I understand what you're saying. But it could also be the case that the estimator is inconsistent and therefore increasing the sample size will not get me a better approximation?

Comment: In general yes, but because of the way sample skewness is defined then the [Law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) guarantees that it is consistent

Comment: @J.Delaney Can you elaborate a bit more on that? For me this is not obvious. In general, [sample skewness is biased](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Sample_skewness)

Comment: there does seem to be something tricky about convergence with the log-normal distribution in particular, although i don't really understand why. possibly because, per wikipedia, it has a moment generating function that is not always defined? if you rerun your code using `np.random.poisson(lam=2, size=samp_size)` it converges almost immediately to $lam^{-.5}$ as it should. Whereas if you run the lognormal with `sigma=2` the results are even more erratic and far from the theoretical skewness.

Comment: @GuilhermeCosta bias is defined for fixed $n$, consistency is defined in the limit $n \to \infty$. The difference between the biased and unbiased versions is related to whether you divide by $n$ or $n-1$, but this becomes negligible in the infinite limit.  Loosely speaking the law of large numbers states that the sample average of any quantity converges to the true mean when $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @J.Delaney. I'm not following you. Bias here means that the "true mean" of the sample skewness is not skewness itself.

Comment: I think you may simply be underestimating the sample sizes needed.  In particular the variance of the sample skewness may be a lot larger than you anticipate.

Comment: @GuilhermeCosta suppose $s_n$ is the sample skewness of $n$ samples where the true skewness is $s_0$, the bias is $E[s_n]-s_0$ (which is a function of $n$) . Consistency means that $\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n = s_0$. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_estimator)

Comment: The rate of convergence is determined by the *sixth* moment of the distribution and sixth powers are quite sensitive to tiny changes in the values: that's why it could take a very, very large simulation to observe convergence.

Comment: It seems understood that skewness here means the moment-based measure but that should be explicit. I can think of many other ways to measure skewness, some remaining popular or very popular. Even historically it's worth noting that Karl Pearson put most emphasis on measuring skewness relative to the mode and mean jointly.